# Corrupted images when downloaded by SSIS project FTP task in SQL Agent job

Tags: sql-server, ssis, tiff

When I run an SSIS project to download tiff images using an FTP task in Visual Studio, (ASCII mode set to false) I can open and view the images just fine.

When I deploy the project and run it via a SQL Server Agent job, the tiff images are corrupted and won't open.

I've tried deleting the existing SSIS job in SQL Server before redeploying, renaming the SSIS project and deploying, etc. Sometimes, if I try to open an image shortly after it's downloaded, I can open it in Microsoft Photo Viewer. If I close it and try to open it again, I'm told it's not a valid bitmap and can't be opened.

Any assistance would be most appreciated.

Comment: "..not a valid bitmap..." - that is very odd, as that message usually indicates an issue in a .BMP or other format that PAINT can open. However, a .tiff file is not a format that PAINT can open, and would generate that error if that image viewer was being used to try to look at the image.  To confirm, manually transfer one of the "corrupted" files to somewhere you can view the image other than the target machine, and try opening the image in a different image viewer.  Also, try setting the images to "Read Only" on download, and see if anything is changing the image files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Opening the downloaded .tiff images using Windows Photo Viewer gives me "Windows Photo Viewer can't open this picture because the file appears to be damaged, corrupted, or is too large." (Files are around 25k.) Opening in PS Elements gives me "Could not complete your request because of a disk error". Another file opened in Elements gives me "Could no complete your request because an unexpected end-of-file was encountered." It's so weird, how it works fine, running the SSIS project in Visual Studio but not when running the deployed project via a SQL Agent job.